# How can I take fullscreen screenshot of website

Tags: java, php, screenshot

I need to get fullscreen shot of website by URL, is there any PHP programs for that or services, if not, is there any Java programs for that purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of ways:

1. Use http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=faq
2. Use webkit engine with some bindings for it: http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/
3. Use mozilla engine in batch mode: http://www.chimeric.de/blog/2007/1018_automated_screenshots_using_bash_firefox_and_imagemagick

Comment: wow, #2 is awesome! Going to have to remember that for the future.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a special version of a browser to "render" the page *after* it's processed by PHP or Java.

You'll most-likely need to set up some custom automation scripts to hit a URL after you ping a server running windows, OSX or a Linux window manager.

There are services out there which will do screen shots for you.

http://www.browsercam.com

http://webthumb.bluga.net/home

to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for me:
Use [selenium webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)
And taking screenshot can be as simple as [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Testing {

    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                                new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), 
                                DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // RemoteWebDriver does not implement the TakesScreenshot class
        // if the driver does have the Capabilities to take a screenshot
        // then Augmenter will add the TakesScreenshot methods to the instance
        WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).
                            getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to use FireFoxDriver. HtmlUnitDriver wont work this way as its headless.

Darn easy!!

Comment: But you need Selenium server running and firefox browser installed for this to work?

Comment: @newbie Firefox browser installed required.But no need for Selenium server running. You just need to import the needed libraries to your java project.

Answer (score 2):

[Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) is a great online resource for this kind of thing; you can submit a URL and have it take full-page screenshots on the latest browsers. If you get a paid subscription or use it on weekends, you'll have access to test on all 22 of its browsers instead of just the most recent. I use this website all the time, I think it's phenomenal.

[BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) is also great, and it supports tons more browsers, but in my experience it's a lot slower too. It's good to use if you *need* to test some browser Litmus doesn't, though.

Comment: I didn't mean that I need to test webpages on different browsers, but rather I need to get screenshots fast from given urls. Is there any open source/free application for that, it really doesn'y have to be php or java, just free software that works...

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the difference. You could still use Litmus or Browsershots for that same thing, just run the test for one browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it yourself if you had a dedicated server. The idea is to launch a X Server and a browser in fullscreen mode, to take a shot, and save it into an image file.

Depending of your utilisation (occasional or intensive), you can adapt the process (i.e. not killing X everytime, etc...) to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question whether you're looking to do this programatically or manually. If manually: there is a great plug-in for Firefox called [Abduction!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3408) that renders a page as an image. Otherwise, Kane's answers have it pretty much covered.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) is the most easiest solution to take screenshots and it will work in Windows and Linux.

**Installinging in Windows:**

Just download file and execute.

**Installining in debian:**

```
apt-get install cutycapt xvfb
```

and running:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" /usr/bin/cutycapt --url=http://www.google.com --out=/home/screenshots/screenshot_name.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). Any one of these should do it:

- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) -> uses 'Webkit' layout engine (Safari/Chromium)
- [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org) -> uses 'Trident' layout engine (Internet explorer)
- [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org) -> uses 'Gecko' layout engine (Firefox)

You can take a screenshot by using following javascript code (saved to file `renderpage.js`):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://en.wikipedia.org', function() {
    page.render('wikipedia.png');
});
```

Then execute via command line:

```
> phantomjs.exe renderpage.js
```

This will create a file `wikipedia.png` with your screenshot.