# How to take a screenshot with HTML-Unit?

Tags: screenshot, htmlunit

I'm from Germany so excuse me for some bad sentences.

I've coded an web-based application, now I want to do a screenshot of the page in one part of the code.

I'm using HTML-Unit, so I want to know how I can do it with it, it would be bad if I needed to change this in the whole project.

Looking forward for an answer,
sincerely,
a guest

Answer (score 6):

HtmlUnit never renders a page visually, so there's no image to capture.

There are tools like [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/) that do a good job of capturing web page images; perhaps there is one that can be accessed via an API, or perhaps you could script something up to interact with a browser.

Also see the accepted answer to [How can I take fullscreen screenshot of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488589/how-can-i-take-fullscreen-screenshot-of-website)

Comment: Thanks man,i'll have a look at FireShot, i need to login to my webpage, is it possible with FireShot?

Comment: but why phantomjs does support it ... ?

Comment: HtmlUnit provides its own GUI-less (for HTML as well as "Browser-Chrome") browser. Phantomjs is based on webkit, so it is a full browser other that the "Browser-Chrome".

Comment: No possible. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1361) comment